# How to implement mysql date_sub() function in Hibernate 3.0

Tags: hibernate

Is it possible in hiberanate to write query like this?

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` where created_at> DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either use a [native SQL query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE created_at > DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)"
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
List result = query.list();
```

Or you can use Hibernate Criteria [Restrictions.sqlRestriction](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-narrowing)

```
String sqlWhere = "{alias}.created_at > DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)";
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyEntity.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(sqlWhere));
List result = criteria.list();
```

Comment: @anoopkattodi: yw, please note that I edited my answer and fixed the code example for `Restrictions.sqlRestriction`.

Comment: can you show us how in Criteria API

Answer (score 4):

You can also extend hibernate's mysql Dialect to support date_add function.

```
public class CommonMySQL5InnoDBDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
    public CommonMySQL5InnoDBDialect() {
        super();
        //mysql date_add function support.
        registerFunction( "date_add_interval", new SQLFunctionTemplate( DateType.INSTANCE, "date_add(?1, INTERVAL ?2 ?3)" ) );
    }
}
```

Then you can use the registered function in you HQL.

```
from tablename where created_at > date_add_interval(curdate(), 7  DAY)
```

Comment: This worked for me, with a minor change in the HQL: from tablename where created_at > date_add_interval(curdate(), 7,  DAY)

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql1 = "select  uh.ServiceDate from tablename  uh WHERE uh.ServiceDate >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)";

Query query1 = session.createSQLQuery(sql1);

 List result = query1.list();

         use this list in HQL

String queryString = "delete  from tablename  u  where  u.serviceDate in (:result)";
query =session.createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameterList("result", result);
```