# HQL String LEFT

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

How do I get records that first 4 characters' match my string using HQL?

This is my HQL statement:

```
Query query = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where substring(user, 4) like :user");

query.setParameter("user", "John");
```

Which returns nothing. However, if I reuse the SQL statement in MySQL and change the word "substring" to `LEFT` then it returns a lot of records.

I've also tried replacing "substring" with "left" in my HQL but it gives me this error when I do:

`org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LEFT`

Comment: Did you try `substring(user, 1, 4) like :user`?

Comment: in HQL your not allowed to use mysql functions. So, better you go with native sql. i.e. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648787/how-to-implement-mysql-date-sub-function-in-hibernate-3-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of `left` requires `substring()` with three arguments.  The second is the offset and the third is the number of characters.  So, to get the first four characters:

```
Query query = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where substring(user, 1, 4) like :user");
```

The expression `substring(user, 4)` usually takes the substring starting at the fourth character to the end of the string (I say "usually" because that is typical behavior of the function but I don't know if HQL exactly does that).

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do this with a like and wildcards instead?

```
Query query = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(
"from User u where u.user like :user");

query.setString("user", "John%");
```

Otherwise do a [native query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)